# Are there optimal days/hours to post questions in order to get visibility and answers?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I know that maybe that's a a silly and weird question, if it's not appropriate please forgive me and feel free to close it.

Given the large amount of questions that the site gets daily, it may happen that a freshly posted question gets rapidly buried under all the newest ones.
I'm wondering if there are some days of the week and/or hours of the day when the chances of getting more views and answers are higher.

Comment: If you're interested now might be a good time to figure out an appropriate [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/new) query to answer your own question. :)

Comment: I'll have a look into it, I have to study it a little bit though :)

Comment: You could also look at it from the other side, when a lot of questions are posted, a lot of people are online. Which might increase your chance for an answer.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3123/what-time-of-the-day-is-super-user-getting-the-least-traffic/3461#3461)

Comment: I've found its really the interestingness of the question (or the sheer trainwreck factor of it) that gets it eyeballs. If its a question you REALLY want an answer to, bounty it. Consider SU to be a *assistive* resource and work on an answer, and update periodically with your findings. In short, write a question that catches eyeballs no matter what, and keep plugging at it as much as you can. You can ignore the gorilla in the room, but can you ignore the gorilla in the room, wearing a tutu and pink lipstick, juggling chainsaw RPGs?

Comment: I find it interesting that across most SE sites, the peak times seem to be typical US working hours.

Comment: All the chat rooms have an average activity distribution per day graph... that's probably a good indicator of activity in the site itself.

Answer (score 2):

To sum up:

The best times to post questions (especially well formed ones that engage the thinking process) would be "banker's hours", US.  So roughly 14:00-21:00 GMT.  That way, even if your question is somewhat "off", you'll still get philanthropists that will reshape your question (like if you went, misguidedly, with a non-question title, or had grammar/clarity errors) into something more engaging.

And during that time, you'll probably get a lot of eyeballs on your question... again, provided you made it something that engages other people's brains.