# Could we be doing our tag edits better?

Tags: discussion, retagging

This came up on chat, and well, there's a few issues to be raised.

Folk who're editing tags tend to get adviced to edit a few tags at a time, and it kinda worked - we've having more people editing tags (yay!) in many cases at a sensible rate (double yay!), but we still end up getting the front page flooded (boo!).

What would be a logical way to settle this? De-emphasise tag edits? Have a tag-busting weekend set by the mods every quarter or so to handle these things? Even more stringent self-control in terms of the number of edits done?

Comment: There is already a request not to bump post when only tags are edited using the [edit tags] link. This would help somewhat, though that would mean not fixing trivial things at the same time as fixing tags. (Which seems wasteful).

Comment: For reference: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/conversation/taggies

Comment: PSA: [Do we care about edit flooding? Should we be doing anything?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/3103)

Comment: De-emphasise tag edits? I don't agree with that, they help clean up the site, and a nature churn of questions is not entirely a bad thing.

Comment: It'd be nice to give us better retagging tools in the first place. We have no way of mass-retagging, say, a list of `[preview]` and `[osx]` questions to `[preview.app]`, or removing tags from a list of questions only. If we had these possibilities, the remaining tag edits – which absolutely require human efforts – would be much smaller in volume and thus less distracting.

Comment: @slhck not sure if the first example can be 100% true. Suppose I'm on [osx] trying to [preview] a .gobbledygook file (or any other file not opened by [preview.app] ). But I agree your suggestions would be a step forward.